# jQuery not returning JSON data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a basic script designed to take some data from a JSON feed and return it in an alert. I can't seem to get my code working though. I am using jQuery and calling on a script hosted on a separate domain. My current code does not even display the alert even though jQuery is being loaded in properly and all the other common issues.

Does anyone have any ideas?

My code is:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.domain.com/api.php?q=test&callback=?",
function(data) {
    alert(data.users[0].firstName);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the server supports JSONP? It looks like the `callback` parameter is not being used.

Comment: What error do you get in your console? If you get cross-scripting errors breaking same-origin policies you might need to try `$.ajax` specifying `jsonp`. I don't remember the exact required setup but have a look at the [**$.ajax()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation, the section on `crossDomain` for the details.

Comment: @user2036031  has nothing to do with your code, open the url in a browser will see that it is not returning jsonp...only json, which is a security restriction for cross domain in browsers

Comment: I seem to be getting a parserror, as it's not jsonp, just json ?

Comment: I'm actually getting a valid response

Comment: I'm not ? -> [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/W4aPk/)

Comment: @user2036031: If you control the other server as well you need to parse the callback parameter and place it in front of the result. For example, if the user supplies `myFn` as the callback parameter, you should send back `myFn({ ..... })` as the result.

Comment: @user2036031: Not sure, I'm not a PHP expert `:)`. I would add your PHP code to the question though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I call

```
http://pulse.wixiy.net/playground/search/api.php?q=wixiy&callback=?
```

in my browser, the response is

```
({"users":[ { "firstName":"Ray", "lastName":"Villalobos", "joined":2012 }, { "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Jones", "joined":2010 } ]})
```

which is a pure JSON string, but no valid JSONP response. For a valid JSONP response, you need a function call which invokes the <strike>JSON string</strike> object literal.

```
jQuery4022random242932crap311({"users":[ { "firstName":"Ray", "lastName":"Villalobos", "joined":2012 }, { "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Jones", "joined":2010 } ]});
```

where *jQuery4022random242932crap311* is some name that jQuery generates when passing in a `?` as parameter for *callback*. Your server needs to read that parameter and create the above answer.